# Determine number of completed tasks in ExecutorCompletionService queue

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm working on a project where there is a large input of data elements that need to be processed. The processing of each is independent of the others and I need a return a result from each. What I'm doing now is creating a `Callable` task for each element to do the processing and using `ExecutorCompletionService` to collect the `Future` result as the threads complete.

I then have another thread that is pulling the `Future` objects from the `ExecutorCompletionService` queue. This thread just spins in an infinite while loop and calls `take()` which blocks until a `Future` shows up in the queue.

What I'm trying to do is avoid the scenario where the queue of `Future` objects grows faster than I pull them off the queue so I'd like to sleep the process that's creating tasks if I get behind on processing the `Future` results.

The problem I'm running into is that I'm not able to find a way to see how many `Future` objects are in the `ExecutorCompletionService` queue. Is there a way to do this?

I could probably keep an external counter that I increment when a new task is created and decrement when a `Future` is processed but this only gets me to the number of outstanding tasks, not the number that are actually done. Any thoughts on the best way to tackle this?

Comment: If you also keep a counter that increments (monotonically) when a new task is submitted, then `totalSubmitted - outstanding = done`, no?

Comment: Can you recirculate the objects via a pool queue and re-use them?  That's what I usually do for inter-thread object flow-control.  If the pool runs out, the thread that produces the tasks gets blocked on the pool queue until some objects get recycled.

Comment: Thank you both. yshavit, when I say "outstanding" above that includes both items that have been submitted and not completed yet and those that have been completed but are still on the queue. I have no way to know how the group of outstanding items is divided between these groups.  Martin, I like this idea and it sounds promising. I'll give it a shot. I appreciate the input.

Comment: Check this out: https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/10/23/creating-a-notifying-blocking-thread-pool-executor.html

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the queues an executor uses using one of the overloaded constructor.  Since queue implements Collection you could just call .size() on that queue.  You will have a queue for the completion and another queue for the executor that the ExecutorCompletionService uses so you could tell how many are submitted and how many are completed between those two.

You'll just need to hold on to those queues after you create them and pass it to whatever is watching the size of them.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html shows the overloaded constructor

Comment: Is it possible for you to expand on "and another queue for the executor that the ExecutorCompletionService uses so you could tell how many are submitted."  Can't find the 'submitted' queue.

Comment: I was referring to the blocking queue given in the ThreadPoolExecutor constructor http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html.  You can then wrap that ThreadPoolExecutor in an ExecutorCompletionService and diff the size of those queues.